# Add indicator/overlay of active flags in review queues for mods

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, moderator-tools

Currently, when visiting a page with active flags, mods see an overlay on the bottom:

[image]

Unfortunately, we don't see these while in the review queues. There's no indication in the queue that a post has flags -- sometimes the flags (especially custom ones) convey extra information on why a post must be closed/reopened/not closed/etc. And since [custom flags are dismissed on closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124515/dont-auto-dismiss-custom-flags-on-close), this can be even more of a problem.

Could we have something prominently indicating that the post has flags in the review queues?