# Has close-flag behavior changed with new closing overhaul?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close

It used to be that when a question was flagged for closing, if the question was closed, the flag was automatically marked as "helpful." Since the recent closing overhaul, I have seen at least a couple questions that I have flagged get closed, without any action taken on the flag. Is this the intended behavior?

I am tagging this as a bug because I do not remember seeing any discussion of this behavior changing.

Example:

I flagged https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8708/uk-ramadan-times-is-it-possible-to-fast-that-long-and-work for closing on Islam.SE. Nobody acted on my flag for a few hours. I mentioned it to one of the mods in chat, and he said that he never saw my flag, but after I linked to the question, he closed it. Currently, though, the flag still seems to be open in my list of flagged posts. The mod says that, as far as he can tell, nobody has taken action on the flag.

Comment: It shouldn't be different, but we may have a bug there. Can you link to some example questions?

Comment: @AnnaLear Added to the question.

Comment: Because mods don't see close flags any more

Comment: oh. It's *that bug* again. Yeah, that should've been marked as helpful; there are a few of these floating around...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187034/putting-questions-on-hold-from-the-moderator-queue-does-not-clear-mod-flags

Comment: random - the king of finding dupes. This should be fixed now, but might be a bit before the fix is deployed.

Comment: @random If mods don't see close flags any more, who *does* see them? What's the point of them?

Comment: @random Does it go to the review queue? I thought that was only when people make close votes.